# Excel Data Validation in VBA - not showing error message if value is other than specified list?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

After running below piece of code, data validation is added to the cells I want, but whenever I type in another value other than the list, no error message is showing up. I want users only to be able to fill in data based on my specified list. How can I do this?

I tried to add the Operator xlEqual and xlBetween, but I can't seem to get it to work.

After running the macro, I can select e.g. following options for the cells from my data validation list:

- A
- B

These are the only options I can choose, but whenever I write in for example "C" in one of the cells it still accepts that value, even though it's not part of my data validation list.

```
Sub ChangeVersionDetails()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowOne As Long
    Dim LastRowEnd As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowOne = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRowEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
    Range("G11:G" & LastRow).Validation.Delete
    Range("I11:T" & LastRow).Validation.Delete
    Range("G11:G" & LastRow).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataVStatus"
    Range("I11:T" & LastRow).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataVInvoicingMonths"
    Range("G" & LastRowOne & ":G" & LastRowEnd).Validation.Delete
    Range("I" & LastRowOne & ":T" & LastRowEnd).Validation.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: [How do I cut and paste your data?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? You can copy everything I wrote right? Haha.

Comment: please give examples of what you are typing in and what your validation criteria are so we can try it out

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I've added a bit of text to my post, because I'm not allowed to post pictures here yet. Does that help clear my issue up?

Comment: Are there are blank cells at the bottom of the validation list ?

Comment: Yes! Do I need to remove those in order for it to work?

Comment: Yes or add a line `Range("G11:G" & LastRow).Validation.IgnoreBlank = False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set IgnoreBlanks to False.

```vb
Sub ChangeVersionDetails()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("G:G,I:T").Validation.Delete
        
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("G11:G" & LastRow).Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataVStatus"
            .IgnoreBlank = False
        End With
        
        With .Range("I11:T" & LastRow).Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=DataVInvoicingMonths"
            .IgnoreBlank = False
        End With
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @DrKedi Usinq unqualified ranges like `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is not recommended because they are the source of many VBA bugs. If you are just starting to program I recommend you avoid it wherever possible.